# css @font-face in ubuntu doesn't work

Tags: html, css, linux, font-face

I developed the web-page under Windows. It has such folders:

```
wwwroot
wwwroot/css
wwwroot/fonts
```

and files

```
wwwroot/css/main.css
wwwroot/fonts/fontaaa.otf
```

main.css file has such a code:

```
@font-face
{
    font-family : 'fontaaa';
    src         : url("../fonts/fontaaa.otf");
}
```

and it sees the font under Windows on my localhost.
Everything is perfect, so I uploaded my project to the linux server.
Everything works fine (the page loads, styles are OK), but the font `fontaaa.otf` is **not displayed**. What is the problem? Spent a lot of time to figure out.

P.S. I've never used `@font-face` before.

P.S.S. the font was downloaded from Internet (was not in the Windows fonts folder).

Comment: show me link of your site than apply font face

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Font face is declared like this :

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Font name';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Font name'), local('Font name-Regular'), url(fontname.woff) format('woff');
}
```

And to apply these fonts you've to do like this :

```
<style>
h1 {
font-family: 'Font Name', Arial/* Just in case if your web fonts didn't load */;
}
</style>

<h1>this will be font-face fonts</h1>
```

For more [web fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts/)

Answer (score 2):

Tried all answers, no luck, but the problem was found. It was the permission for the fonts folder.
Thank you everybody.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
@font-face
{
 font-family : 'fontaaa';
 src         : url("../fonts/fontaaa.otf");
}

p, html, body {
 font-family:fontaaa;
 src: url('../fonts/fontaaa.otf');
}

@font-face {
 font-family: 'Font name';
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 400;
 src: local('Font name'), local('Font name-Regular'), url(fontname.woff) format('woff');
}
```

that worked for me (you can put another tag instead of the p)